# How to await when all http requests are finished using spring webClient?

Tags: java, resttemplate, spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-webclient

I want to execute http request for each queue element. These requests shoule be called in parallel.
Also I need to await the termination of all requests.

I developed the following code:

```
 List<Mono<MyResponseDTO>> monoList = queue.stream()
                .map(jobStatusBunch -> webClient
                        .post()
                        .uri("localhost:8080/api/some/url")
                        .bodyValue(convertToRequestDto(someBean))
                        .retrieve()
                        .toEntity(String.class)
                        .filter(HttpEntity::hasBody)
                        .map(stringResponseEntity -> {
                            try {
                                return objectMapper.readValue(stringResponseEntity.getBody(), MyResponseDTO.class);
                            } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                                log.error("Can't parse", e);
                                return null;
                            }
                        })
                        .doOnNext(myResponseDTO -> {
                            log.info("doOnNext is invoked");
                        })
                ).collect(Collectors.toList());
          //await when all MONOs are completed

log.info("Start waiting for {}", monoList);
Mono<Void> mono = Flux.fromIterable(monoList)
        .flatMap(Function.identity())
        .then();
log.info("Finished waiting for {}", monoList);
```

and I see following log when queue has single element:

```
2019-11-19 19:17:17.733  INFO 5896 --- [   scheduling-1] c.b.m.service.MyService     : Start waiting for [MonoPeek]
2019-11-19 19:17:25.988  INFO 5896 --- [   scheduling-1] c.b.m.service.MyService     : Finished waiting for [MonoPeek]
2019-11-19 19:17:26.015 TRACE 5896 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.w.r.f.client.ExchangeFunctions       : [c42c1c2] HTTP POST localhost:8080/api/some/url, headers={}
2019-11-19 19:17:48.230  INFO 5896 --- [tor-http-nio-11] c.b.m.service.MyService     : doOnNext is invoked
```

So this code doesn't allow to await request termination.

How could I achieve it ?

### P.S.

looks like `Flux.merge(monoList).blockLast()` is smth I need. Will it work correct ?

Comment: Why you need to await the termination of the request? You should do the additional work afterwards in a reactive way, too

Comment: @Joker it is out of scope - I really need it.

Comment: `blockLast` is that what youre looking for then for Flux. 

But, no need to collect Mono<MyResponseDTO> to a list. Just call `block` of the Mono you get.

Comment: @Joker  if I call block  on each mono it will cause of sequential requests execution. I want to make requests in parallel

Answer (score 1):

## Simple case

Use this to execute requests in parallel and wait until they complete:

```
List<Mono<MyResponseDTO>> monoList = queue
        .stream()
        .map(requestDTO ->
                webClient
                    .post()
                    .uri("localhost:8080/api/some/url")
                    .bodyValue(requestDTO)
                    .retrieve()
                    .bodyToMono(MyResponseDTO.class))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

// This will execute all requests in parallel and wait until they complete,
// or throw an exception if any request fails.
List<MyResponseDTO> responses = Flux.merge(monoList).collectList().block();
```

## Verification

You might want to set logging of `reactor.netty.http.client` to `DEBUG` to see no extra requests are made. That can happen for example if you accidentally use both `mono#subscribe` and `mono#block`.

## More complex case with CompletableFuture

If you want to separate the handling of responses and the waiting for requests to complete, then CompletableFutures can be used:

```
List<Mono<MyResponseDTO>> webClientMonos = getMonos();

// Start executing requests in parallel.
List<CompletableFuture<MyResponseDTO>> futures = webClientMonos.stream()
        .map(mono -> mono.toFuture())
        .collect(toList());
for (CompletableFuture<MyResponseDTO> future : futures) {
    future.thenAccept(responseDTO -> {
        // Do something with a response when it arrives at some point.
        // ...
    });
}

// ...

// Block until all requests have completed.
for (CompletableFuture<MyResponseDTO> future : futures) {
    try {
        // Maybe WebClient has been configured with timeouts,
        // but it doesn't hurt to have a timeout here, too.
        future.get(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    } catch (ExecutionException | TimeoutException ex) {
        // ExecutionException is thrown if HTTP request fails.
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
Flux<MyResponseDTO> responses = queue.stream()
     .flatMap(jobStatusBunch -> webClient
                    .post()
                    .uri("localhost:8080/api/some/url")
                    .bodyValue(convertToRequestDto(someBean))
                    .retrieve()
                    .toEntity(MyResponseDTO.class));

 Mono<Void> workDone = response.then();
```

This is simple and should do the job. By default (if I'm not mistaken), the subscriber will request for `256` elements which means that you'll get maximum 256 HTTP requests processed in parallel. This can depend on the connection pool configured on the HTTP client; by default, on Reactor Netty, the maximum number of TCP channels is higher than that.

Various Reactor operators, including `flatMap`, offer variants with a `concurrency` method parameter to control the maximum concurrency there.

Your solution with `Flux.merge` with a list of `Mono` would be equivalent. On the other hand, using `Flux.concat` would not be what you're looking for since it would be subscribing to `Mono` as elements are requested, so you might not the get maximum concurrency you want.

Comment: Should I invoke anything on workDone to await termination?